# ordering the placement of 3 divs

Tags: html, css

I would like to place the middle portion div on top for a @media query -- and then I would like to stack the left portion and right portion divs below it side by side for a responsive and clean looking design, possibly for mobile as well.

Here is my code -- any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="needhelpagain.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Arvo|Josefin+Slab|Lato|Old+Standard+TT|Open+Sans|PT+Sans|PT+Serif|Roboto|Ubuntu|Vollkorn|Dancing+Script">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<header></header>


<div class="container">


<div class="left-portion"></div>


<div class="middle-portion">Blank Content</div>


<div class="right-portion"></div>

</div>


</body>
</html>

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
    background-color:#1a0000;
}

.container{
    margin:auto;
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:white;
}

header{
    padding:50px;
    background-color:#000000;

}

.left-portion{
    width:22%;
    height:1200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#fff3e5;


}

.middle-portion{
    width:56%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:'old standard tt';
    text-align:center;
}

.right-portion{
    width:22%;
    height:1200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#fff3e5;
    font-family:'vollkorn';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to get away with making the div on top you have it labeled as left .. Make that 100% width then the other 2 divs set as 50% and the set all of the divs in the container to position relative. And the bottom divs to float left.

```
    <style>
.container{
    height: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container div{
    position: relative;
}
.topDiv{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
.botDivs{
    width:50%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left
}
.green{
    background:green;
}
.red{
    background:red;
}
.blue{
    background:blue;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
<div class="topDiv red"></div>
<div class="botDivs green"></div>
<div class="botDivs blue"></div>
</div>
```